# I want to get the first child of element, get the childs text and check if it equals a given string

Tags: javascript, protractor, e2e-testing

I am new to e2e and unfortunately, I cannot get expect() to work as I intend it to.

The e2e test is NOT for an angular page, I've already turned waiting for angular off. The element ('myClassName') has only one child and nothing else in it, unfortunately, I cannot access the child directly, since it has no unique property.

```
 this.check = async (stringg)  => {
expect(element.all(by.className('myClassName')).get(0).getText()).to.eventually.equal(stringg)
}
```

Error message:

```
 E/launcher - stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: Hard to fathom what the problem is with that two lines of code. But likely a missing `await` is the cause. Would it be possible to update the question with entire `it` block if not entire `describe` ?